# Nuxt 3 Failed to resolve import dist.plugin.26632bfc.js. Does the file exist?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

When I try to import module in my file `nuxt.config.ts` like this:

```js
modules: [
    ['nuxt-mail', {
      message: {
        to: process.env.MAIL_TO,
      },
      smtp: {
        host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
        port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
        // service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
          pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS,
        },
      },
    }],
  ],
```

I got this error

> Failed to resolve import "/Users/guillaume/Desktop/Sites/Perso/nuxt-3/.nuxt/Users/guillaume/Desktop/Sites/Perso/nuxt-3/.nuxt/dist.plugin.26632bfc.js" from "virtual:nuxt:/Users/guillaume/Desktop/Sites/Perso/nuxt-3/.nuxt/plugins/client.mjs". Does the file exist?

As you can see, I have double path `/Users/guillaume/Desktop/Sites/Perso/nuxt-3/.nuxt/`

Someone understand why path is wrong and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Hm, not sure what happened here but you may probably try to delete the `.nuxt` directory (used for cache purposes) + install your dependecies again (not a direct cause but may help IMO).

Comment: I'm the dev of nuxt-mail and getting myself into Nuxt 3 now

Answer (score 0):

I didn't saw that you were using the `nuxt-mail` module here, my bad.

UPDATE: `nuxt-mail` [now supports Nuxt3](https://github.com/dword-design/nuxt-mail/issues/108#issuecomment-1372424710).

Comment: Nuxt 3 support for nuxt-mail is implemented.